# Why is my fail msg not being displayed when lookup('vars', item) fails?

Tags: ansible

I need to modify a playbook that expects to have a yaml file loaded via `--extra-vars` because the extra vars file needs to be generated with user input every time it's used.

This playbook currently overwrites a file and then modifies it, replacing placeholders with the values in `my-extra-vars.yml`. This is a destructive step; if a variable is not defined then the placeholder is left untouched.

This is working, sort of, but the error message is not what I expect or want.

```yaml
vars:
  - required_vars:
    - 'varname1'
    - 'varname2'

tasks:
  - name: Check for required variables
    fail:
      msg: "variable '{{item}}' is not defined"
    when: lookup('vars', item) is undefined
    with_items: "{{required_vars}}"
```

Running the playbook as `ansible playbook -K --extra-vars '@test-vars.yml' test.yml` with only `varname1` defined gives me the following output.

```
TASK [Check for required variables] **************************************************************************************
skipping: [127.0.0.1] => (item=varname1)
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'lookup('vars', item) is undefined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (lookup('vars', item) is undefined): No variable found with this name: varname2\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/me/projects/test/test.yml': line 21, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Check for required variables\n      ^ here\n"}
```

If all variables are defined, then there is no syntax error. Otherwise, it is dying, so at least that aspect of the problem is managed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the lookup, itself is failing, so the `when` condition fails and your tasks is not failing as it *normally* should.

A way around this failure would be to use the [`default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html#parameter-default) of the `vars` lookup, but from there it all depends what are your acceptable values for those variables.

An example, considering I do not want blank string in them would be:

```yaml
- name: Check for required variables
  fail:
    msg: "variable '{{item}}' is not defined"
  when: lookup('vars', item, default='') == ''
  loop: "{{ required_vars }}"
  vars:
    required_vars:
      - 'varname1'
      - 'varname2'
```

Which would yield your expected:

```
TASK [Check for required variables] **************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=varname1) => changed=false 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: varname1
  msg: variable 'varname1' is not defined
failed: [localhost] (item=varname2) => changed=false 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: varname2
  msg: variable 'varname2' is not defined
```

---

A better way, though, is to use the [`undef` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-mandatory-values), this way, if you do template the variable, they will automatically raise the undefined hint provided.

Given the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    varname1: "{{ undef(hint='Please provide a value for `varname1`') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ varname1 }}"
```

It yields:

```
atal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
    The error was: {{ undef(hint='Please provide a value for `varname1`') }}: 
    Please provide a value for `varname1`
```